# which linux kernel code create /dev/sda or /dev/sda1 for SATA device?

Tags: linux-kernel

Someone told me udev create /dev/sda device when SATA device is detected. 
But as I read or understand udev. udev can run program or add symblink but can not create device /dev/sda.

[Image related to device node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYaD8.png)

Comment: It's created under corresponding class in `sysfs`.

Comment: I did not get you. could please explain me in little bit in detail?

Comment: Run `ls -l /sys/class/ata_device/` before and after connecting a device.